# Find a new quadratic form through change of variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Consider a quadratic form $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x_i ^2$$ $f$ represents $0$ non-trivially. Then I need to show that by a linear change of variables, I can get the following quadratic form $$f(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}b_i y_i ^2 - 2 b_ny_{n-1}y_n$$

Now as suggested in [Find a change in variable that will reduce the quadratic form to a sum of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727030/find-a-change-in-variable-that-will-reduce-the-quadratic-form-to-a-sum-of-square) by Gerry Myerson, I put $x = Py$ , for some $n \times n$ matrix $P$. Then $$f(x)=f(Py)=(Py)^tAPy=y^t(P^tAP)y$$ My question is how do I find the matrix $P$ s.t. I get $f(y)$ as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a complete answer, just some ideas. If we take:
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} 
    b_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 &        & b_{n-2} & 0  & 0\\
 0 &  \dots & 0 & 0 & -b_n \\
0 & \dots & 0 &-b_n & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

then $f(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}b_i y_i ^2 - 2 b_ny_{n-1}y_n = y^{t} B y $. So we are interest in finding an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{t} A P = B$ with $A=\text{diag}(a_1, a_2, \dots a_{n-1})$.

Since $B$ is symmetric with set of eigenvalues $\text{spec}(B)=\{ b_1, b_2, \dots b_{n-2}, \pm b_n \}$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that 
$$ B=QDQ^{t} $$
where $D=\text{diag}(b_1, b_2, \dots b_{n-2}, \pm b_n)$. Hence we must find $P$ such that:

$$ P^{t}AP=QDQ^{t} \Longrightarrow D=(PQ)^{t}A(PQ). $$
Where in the last equation all matrices are known exept $P$, but we must find a clever idea for computations. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I should emphasize that the linear change of variables for a quadratic form is typically taken to be a matrix $P$ of determinant $1,$ with transformed matrix $P^T A P.$ It is not generally required that $P$ be orthogonal.

The question as stated is false for $n-1$ positive diagonal elements and a single zero. It is true if there are at least two zeros, just permute so those are at the end, your $b_n$ becomes zero. Permuting by a matrix $P$ of determinant $+1,$  that is $P^T A P$ for a pair of diagonal entries, is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
u & 0 \\
0 & v
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
v & 0 \\
0 & u
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If there are at least one positive diagonal entry and one negative, first consider their product to be $-1.$ Permute, two entries at a time, so that these are the last two diagonal entries.
Then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{w}{2} \\
\frac{1}{w} & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
w & 0 \\
0 & - \frac{1}{w}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{w} \\
- \frac{w}{2} & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This is a small part of Lemma 2.1 on [page 15 of *Rational Quadratic Forms* by Cassels,](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html) that a regular isotropic quadratic space contains a hyperbolic plane. I recommend Cassels.

If the product of the two diagonal elements is $- c^2$ for real $c,$ we can find an appropriate $w$ to give
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{w}{2} \\
\frac{1}{w} & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
cw & 0 \\
0 & - \frac{c}{w}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{w} \\
- \frac{w}{2} & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & c \\
c & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$